# How to create nested url on WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, permalinks

I want to have nested url on my wordpress site, having woocommerce:

```
site.com/shop/hair/shampoo
```

- shop - shop page,
- hair - category page,
- shampoo - product page

after I changed the permalink settings, it partially worked:

[image]

---

If I go to page category, I get 404 error

```
site.com/shop/hair
```